# User defined library

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me

I am a newbie at J2ME. Recently, I've shifted from Netbeans to Eclipse because of some internal constraints. 
I am making an App which makes use of a user-defined library. This library has only a jar file.
Now, in Netbeans there were no problems. But in eclipse, I am unable to access the classes defined in the jar file included in my library. The exception thrown is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the jar through:

`right click your project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Add External Jars` and select your jar from there?

In case the jar is in your project dir, you can use "Add Jars" (not External).

I assume you have done it, so to the next step:

How are you running your application? In the `Run Configurations` there is a `classpath` tab - make sure your jar is present there as well.

Comment: hi...thanks for responding. But it doesnt seem to work.
Any other suggestions??

Comment: first answer my question - how are you running your application.

Comment: I am not really able to understand your question....I go to run configuration, add the midlet name and project source and run it.

Comment: what about right-click your midlet and Run it?

With your approach - do you add the library to the classpath tab, as I said in my answer?

Comment: hmm..i couldnt find any classpath tab, so i added the library in the source tab in run configuration.
And tried running via right clicking on the midlet, but in vain

Comment: where exactly is the classpath option??